# Alternative string terminate

Tags: javascript, string, terminate

I just wanted to ask, if there are some alternative (different than quotes) string terminators in Javascript? I've heard about the NULL byte that used to work on IE.

I know that a string can't be over 1 line because the next line is treated as next line of code, however in this case javascript just reports "unterminated string" error.

Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, you can span a string over multiple lines by using a ``\`` as the last character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either escape the newline:

```
var a = "beginning of string\
```

rest of string";

or you can use string concatenation:

```
var a = "beginning of string" +
        "rest of string";
```